# Putting All Logical Expression Variables Into An Array

Tags: java, arrays, truthtable

I am writing a program that will print the truth table of an expression. Currently my code takes a logical expression and turns it into the two arrays as shown in input. I need help in meeting the following output for my algorithm

Example: Logical Expression = ((-A)+B))+C

Input:

logExp: [(, (, -, A, ), +, B, ), ), +, C]

indepVar: [A, B, C]

Expected Output:

array: [A, B, C, (-A), (-A)+B, ((-A)+B))+C] //ok with or without brackets.

Current Output I get with this algorithm:

array:[A, B, C, (-A)+B)]

Code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> Head(ArrayList<Character> logExp, ArrayList<Character> indepVar){
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
    int count = 0;
    String str = "";

    for(int i = 0; i < indepVar.size(); i++){
        array.add(indepVar.get(i).toString());
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < logExp.size(); i++){
        if(logExp.get(i)== '(')
            count++;
        else if(logExp.get(i) == ')')
            count--;
        if(count > 0)
            str += logExp.get(i);
        if(count == 0 && str != ""){
            array.add(str);
            str = "";
        }

    }
    return array;
```

I am not very experience with recursive functions but I attempted to do and algorithm similar to the algorithm above that should work recursively by taking a string and adding everything between brackets to an array.

Then passing that again as an argument to the same algorithm until all expressions between brackets are added to the array. But it didnt work very well and I don't know I went wrong. Any ideas?

Here is the code:

```
public static ArrayList<String> rec(String str){
    int count = 0;
    char ch;
    String s = "";
    ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        ch = str.charAt(i);

        if(ch == '(')
            count++;
        if(count > 0)
            s += ch;

        if(ch == ')')
            count--;

        if(count == 0 && s != ""){
            s = s.substring(1, s.length()-1);
            array.add(s);
            count = 0;
            return rec(s);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: What else have you tried?

Comment: I have tried changing the algorithm a lot, its been two days but I haven't gotten anywhere, especially dealing with the (-A) and how to seperate it from the bigger expression.  Any help is appreaciated!

Answer (score 0):

What your current algorithm does is add anything inside a set of parentheses. Judging by the nature of this problem, I think it should be recursive.

A simple solution (in pseudo code) would be:

```
main_method (indep, expr):
    add all of indep to array
    recur (expr,array)

recur (expr,array):
    find expression in parens
    recur (thing_in_parens,array)
    add expr to array
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this would work exactly to get your expected output, but if youre trying to break up a logical formula based on the main operator like if I had the formula:

(AvB) -> C

the main operator would be "->". And in the formula you gave:

((-A)+B))+C

it would be "+". Then you might be able to iterate over the formula string and keep track of left and right parentheses in count variables noting that when you get to the point in the formula where the left and right counts are equal the character immediately after will be the main operator something like:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        if (formula.charAt(i) == '(')
            countl++;
        if (formula.charAt(i) == ')')
            countr++;
        if ((countl == countr) && countl != 0) {
            indexOfOp = i;
            break;
        }
    }
```

now if you want to do this recursively you might use this general idea:

```
    ArrayList<String> subFormulas = new ArrayList<>();
String[][] parseFormulas(String formula) {
    base case where if formula doesnt have parentheses return the operands 

    subFormulas.add(formula);
    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        if (formula.charAt(i) == '(')
            countl++;
        if (formula.charAt(i) == ')')
            countr++;
        if ((countl == countr) && countl != 0) {
            indexOfOp = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    // for a formula "A op B"
    parseFormulas(formula.substring(0, indexOfOp + 1));//A
    parseFormulas(formula.substring(indexOfOp + 2, formula.length()));//B

}
```

This method might work but it could just be easier, if youre trying to print a truth table, to use [postfix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) notation to parse and calculate the truth value of the formula. You combine that with getting all combos of truth values for  your variables to make truth table. Here's my poor attempt at implementing this idea:

```
public class TruthTable {

//highest order of precedence going from the right of array
char[] operators = {'<', '>', 'v', '&', '~'};

//list of variables
char[] alphabet = {
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g',
        'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
        'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B',
        'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
        'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',
        'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'W',
        'X', 'Y', 'Z'
};


public static void printString(String[][] s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("{");
        for (int j = 0; j < s[0].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(s[i][j]);
            if (!(j == s[0].length - 1)) {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("}");
    }

}
public static int indexOf(ArrayList<Character> list, Character c) {
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (list.get(i) == c) {
            index = i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
public static boolean contains(ArrayList<Character> list, Character c) {
    for (Character i : list) {
        if (i == c) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
public static boolean contains(char[] chars, Character c) {
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        if (chars[i] == c) return true;
    }
    return false;
}


/**
 * used this w/ makeTable to print to console
 */
public static String[][] makeEven(String[][] table){
    for(int j=0;j<table[0].length;j++){
        int largestString=0;
        for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++){
            if(table[i][j].length()>largestString)
                largestString = table[i][j].length();
        }
        for(int i=0;i<table.length;i++){
            if(table[i][j].length()<largestString){
                int diff=((largestString-table[i][j].length())/2);
                int middle=((diff/2)+1);
                String tmp = table[i][j];
                table[i][j]="";
                int count=0;
                while(table[i][j].length()!=largestString){
                    count++;
                    if(count!=middle)
                        table[i][j] += " ";

                    else
                        table[i][j] +=tmp;

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return table;
}

/**
 * POSSIBLY WORST METHOD EVER DEVISED FOR PRINTING A TABLE
 * @return the table to be printed
 */
public static String[][] makeTable(String formula, char[] variables, ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> combos) {
    int spacing = 2;
    String[][] result = new String[combos.size() + 3][(spacing + 1) * variables.length + formula.length() + 2 * spacing];
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        int count = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                if(j < (variables.length * (spacing + 1) + spacing)) {
                    if ((j % (spacing + 1) == 2)) {
                        result[i][j] = "" + variables[k];
                        k++;
                    } else result[i][j] = "*";
                }
                else{
                    if (j == (variables.length * (spacing + 1) + spacing + (formula.length() / 2))) {
                        result[i][j]=formula;
                    } else result[i][j] = " ";
                }
            }
            if (i == 0 || i == (result[0].length - 1) || i == 2)
                result[i][j] = "*";

            if (j < (variables.length * (spacing + 1) + spacing) && (i > 2)) {
                if (j % (spacing + 1) == 2) {
                    if (combos.get(i - 3).get(count))
                        result[i][j] = "True";
                    else result[i][j] = "False";
                    count++;
                } else result[i][j] = "*";
            }
            else if(i>2) {
                if (j == (variables.length * (spacing + 1) + spacing + (formula.length() / 2))) {
                    if (combos.get(i - 3).get(count)) result[i][j] = "True";
                    else result[i][j] = "False";
                    count++;
                } else result[i][j] = " ";
            }

        }
    }
    return result;
}


/**
 * @param n number of variables in logic formula
 * @return 2d list where each 1d list has T/F vals
 *         for that row in table
 */
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> combos(int n) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= Math.pow(2, n); i++) {
        ArrayList<Boolean> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
        String combo = Integer.toBinaryString(i - 1);
        while (combo.length() < n) {
            combo = "0" + combo;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < combo.length(); j++) {
            if (combo.charAt(j) == '0')
                tmp.add(false);
            else tmp.add(true);
        }
        output.add(tmp);
    }
    return output;
}

/**
 * @param formula logic formula like "(a&b)>c"
 * @return character array of variables in formula
 */
public char[] getVariables(String formula) {
    String vars = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        if (contains(alphabet, formula.charAt(i)))
            vars += formula.charAt(i);
    }
    char[] variables = new char[vars.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < vars.length(); i++) {
        variables[i] = vars.charAt(i);
    }
    return variables;
}

/**
 * @param formula string to test
 * @return true if parentheses are validly placed
 */
public boolean parenMatch(String formula) {
    Stack parenStack = new Stack();
    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        char token = formula.charAt(i);
        if (token == '(') {
            parenStack.push(token);
        } else if (token == ')') {
            if (parenStack.isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }
            parenStack.pop();
        }
    }
    if (parenStack.isEmpty()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Shunting-yard
 *
 * @param formula logic formula
 * @return postfix expression
 */
public String parseFormula(String formula) {
    if (!parenMatch(formula)) {
        System.out.println("this formula:  '" + formula + "' doesnt work, parentheses dont match");
        String result = "";
        return result;
    }
    ArrayList<Character> infix = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        infix.add(formula.charAt(i));
    }
    ArrayList<Character> removeFromInfix = new ArrayList<Character>();//remove spaces from input
    for (Character c : infix) {
        if (c == ' ') removeFromInfix.add(c);
    }
    for (Character c : removeFromInfix) {
        infix.remove(c);
    }


    ArrayList<Character> operators = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<Character> alphabet = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.operators.length; i++) {
        operators.add(this.operators[i]);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < this.alphabet.length; i++) {
        alphabet.add(this.alphabet[i]);
    }


    Stack<Character> operatorStack = new Stack<Character>();
    Queue<Character> inputTokens = new Queue<Character>();
    Queue<Character> output = new Queue<Character>();


    for (int i = 0; i < infix.size(); i++) {
        inputTokens.enqueue(infix.get(i));
    }

    while ((!inputTokens.isEmpty())) {
        Character token = inputTokens.dequeue();

        //if its a character in alphabet
        if (contains(alphabet, token)) output.enqueue(token);

            //if its an operator
        else if (contains(operators, token)) {
            if (operatorStack.empty()) {
                operatorStack.push(token);
            } else {
                Character topOperator = operatorStack.peek();
                //while (precedence of op on top of operator stack > token) enqueue op onto result
                while ((indexOf(operators, operatorStack.peek())) > (indexOf(operators, token))) {
                    output.enqueue(topOperator);
                    topOperator = operatorStack.peek();
                    operatorStack.pop();

                    if (operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                operatorStack.push(token);
            }
        } else if (token == '(') {
            operatorStack.push(token);
        } else if (token == ')') {
            while (!(operatorStack.peek().equals('('))) {
                output.enqueue(operatorStack.peek());
                operatorStack.pop();
            }
            operatorStack.pop();
        }
    }//end while

    while (!operatorStack.isEmpty()) {
        output.enqueue(operatorStack.pop());
    }

    String result = "";
    for (char c : output) {
        result += c;
    }
    return result;
}

/**
 * @param postfix given from parseFormula
 * @param inputs  true and false values in the order the variables are listed in postfix
 * @return resulting true or false value of posfix expression
 */
public boolean evalPostfix(String postfix, ArrayList<Boolean> inputs) {
    //to make sure not to change the inputs outside of this function
    ArrayList<Boolean> inputsCopy = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {
        inputsCopy.add(inputs.get(i));
    }

    Stack<Boolean> output = new Stack<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < postfix.length(); i++) {
        char token = postfix.charAt(i);
        if (!contains(operators, token))//if variable
            output.push(inputsCopy.remove(0));

        else {//if operator
            boolean result = false;
            if (token == '~')
                result = !output.pop();
            else {
                boolean A = output.pop();
                boolean B = output.pop();
                if (token == '&')
                    result = A && B;
                else if (token == 'v')
                    result = A || B;
                else if (token == '>')
                    result = !B || A;
            }
            output.push(result);
        }
    }
    return output.pop();
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TruthTable t = new TruthTable();

    String formula = "((pvq)&(jvk))>r";
    char[] variables = t.getVariables(formula);

    String postfix = t.parseFormula(formula);
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Boolean>> combos = combos(variables.length);
    for (ArrayList<Boolean> combo : combos) {
        combo.add(t.evalPostfix(postfix, combo));
    }
    printString(makeEven(t.makeTable(formula,variables,combos)));

}
```

}

Ive barely tested it but I think this idea could still be decent.